# Laser cutting - ignition

Tags: laser

How is that sometimes laser cutting by burning material or "flame cutting" causes ignition of the whole material like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Ge8pMg33bq4) where the whole paper starts to burn and sometimes doesn't allowing precise cutting like [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wxgzJQdrXGg)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If I wanted to laser cut combustible materials, I would do so in an inert atmosphere - no oxygen, no burning. Of course you can never prevent local charring - chemical decomposition due to heat - but you can prevent a chemical reaction with oxygen by removing the oxygen.

Other than that, careful control of the laser intensity and time profile can help: a small intense pulse will vaporize material locally without heating the bulk, and this means that insufficient material will heat up to start a fire. In essence there is no "hot fuel" if you tweak the parameters just so.